# MapStruct avoid return object creation

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have two models and a mapper,

```
public class Form {
    private int x1;
    private int x2;
    private int x3;
    private int x4;
    // Constructor and getters setters ommited.
}

public class Domain {
    private int x1;
    private int x2;
    private int x3;
    private int x4;
    // Constructor and getters setters ommited.
}

@Mapper
public interface DomainMapper {

    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(target = "x1", ignore = true),
        @Mapping(target = "x2", ignore = true)})
    Domain toDomain(Form form);
}
```

This is my example,

```
// I create a form object.
Form form = new Form();
form.setX1(1);
form.setX2(2);
form.setX3(3);
form.setX4(4);

// I create a Domain object.
Domain domain = new Domain();
domain.setX1(100);
domain.setX2(200);

// Map the form to domain.
domain = domainMapper.toDomain(form);
System.out.print(domain.getX1()); // => shows "0" instead of "100"
```

MapStruct is generating source code which inside creates a new Domain object.
Running the last command `domain = DomainMapper.toDomain(form);` my previous domain object will be lost. Is there any way to transfer properties from a Form object to a Domain object that I have already created, using MapStruct?
I tried something like this, but it is not working,

```
@Mapper
public interface DomainMapper {

    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(target = "x1", ignore = true),
        @Mapping(target = "x2", ignore = true)})
    Domain toDomain(Form form, Domain referenceToExistingObject);
}
```

I used it like this, but it doesn't work,

```
domainMapper.toDomain(form, domain);
```

Comment: void updateDomain(Form form, @MappingTarget Domain domain)

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! You saved my day.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will set as answer the @seneque's comment.
I can pass a reference of an object, so the mapper will not create a new one, by using the annotation [@MappingTarget](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#updating-bean-instances).

```
void updateDomain(Form form, @MappingTarget Domain domain)
```